# For all real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a \not = 0$, $x = \dfrac{-b}{2a}$ is a maximiser of the function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, quadratics

Is it true to say that, for all real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a \not = 0$, $x = \dfrac{-b}{2a}$ is a maximiser of the function $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$? If not, please give a counterexample to show that the conjecture is false.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to confirm/deny this.

Comment: What happens if $a > 0$?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @dxiv You're right. $x = 0$ would be the supposed maximum point according to $x = \dfrac{-b}{2a}$, but $x^2$ would actually diverge to infinity, right?

Comment: @ThePointer $x=-b/2a$ is a local extremum (which, in the case of quadratics, is also a global extremum). For $a \gt 0$ the extremum is a minimum.

Comment: @dxiv I understand. Thank you all for the assistance. :)